# How compatible are KSYSTEM_TIME and FILETIME on Windows?

Tags: windows, internals

I've been using information from [`KUSER_SHARED_DATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-kuser_shared_data) ([useful overview](http://terminus.rewolf.pl/terminus/structures/ntdll/_KUSER_SHARED_DATA_combined.html)) in various contexts in the past. Some of the first members are of type `KSYSTEM_TIME` and the way they're laid out is required due to keep ISRs non-blocking [according to this source](https://osm.hpi.de/wrk/2007/08/getting-os-information-the-kuser_shared_data-structure/).

For reference (from `wdm.h`):

```
typedef struct _KSYSTEM_TIME {
    ULONG LowPart;
    LONG High1Time;
    LONG High2Time;
} KSYSTEM_TIME, *PKSYSTEM_TIME;
```

As we can see this is practically equivalent to a `LARGE_INTEGER`/`LONGLONG` apart from the second "high" member (for the above mentioned reason).

Alas, `FILETIME` is (from `winbase.h`):

```
typedef struct _FILETIME {
    DWORD dwLowDateTime;
    DWORD dwHighDateTime;
} FILETIME;
```

... and therefore all unsigned and for all intents and purposes equivalent to a `ULARGE_INTEGER`/`ULONGLONG`.

Now it makes sense that `KSYSTEM_TIME` can be negative as for the time zone offset (`KUSER_SHARED_DATA::TimeZoneBias`) but the value range is of course "halved" for the signed version and so it limits compatibility between the structs.

But it begs **the question**: is it alright to coerce the fields of `KSYSTEM_TIME` -- if known to be a time rather than a time delta -- into a `FILETIME`?

PS: the [`SYSTEMTIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime) used by `FileTimeToSystemTime`/`SystemTimeToFileTime` corresponds more (conceptually, not 1:1) to [`TIME_FIELDS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-time_fields) struct and is not what the above question is about.

Comment: If you disassemble `GetSystemTime()` or `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` on x64 you will see they read the value into a single 64-bit register, so it should be safe (though not contractually guaranteed) to do so.

Comment: @Luke By "not contractually guaranteed" you basically mean I am depending on implementation-defined behavior (as I already do pretty much when using `KUSER_SHARED_DATA` and the native API), right? Thanks, this helps a lot. I think this is a perfectly acceptable answer (at least to me it would be). I verified it in IDA for `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` and you are of course right.